# Query DataTable from ashx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I would like to fill a DataTable with the Page_Load event, then be able to access it from the ashx handler page when an Ajax call is sent from the client side. Currently, the DataTable is filled every time I make an Ajax call to the handler page, which makes it a bit on the slow side. Here's what I currently do:

Default.aspx.cs

```
public DataTable fillSCOMDTts()
    {
        //SCOM TableAdapter and DataTable
        dsCIInfoTableAdapters.vManagedEntityTableAdapter taSCOM;
        taSCOM = new dsCIInfoTableAdapters.vManagedEntityTableAdapter();

        dsCIInfo.vManagedEntityDataTable dtSCOM = new dsCIInfo.vManagedEntityDataTable();
        taSCOM.Fill(dtSCOM);

        return dtSCOM;
    }
```

Ajax call from client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/FindFootprint.ashx?queryStr=' + strParameter,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
              //do stuff
});
```

FindFootprint.ashx.cs

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string strParameter = context.Request.QueryString["queryStr"];

        bool binSCOMts = false;

        Default d = new Default();
        DataTable dtSCOMts = d.fillSCOMDTts();

        var qstSCOMts = (from row in dtSCOMts.AsEnumerable()
                       let fieldName = row.Field<string>("DisplayName")
                       where fieldName.ToLower().Contains(strParameter)
                       select fieldName).ToArray();

        if (qstSCOMts.Length > 0)
        {
            binSCOMts = true;
        }

        JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
        JO.Add("assetName", strParameter);
        JO.Add("inSCOMts", binSCOMts.ToString());

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
        context.Response.Write(JO.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A handler is not really supposed to know anything about code/objects outside of itself.

If you're able to not use the handler in this case then you could set a `private static DataTable MyTable;` in your page.

Then on your `page_load` populate this static property.

You should then be able to access this property inside a web method that you call from you Ajax. The web method would be part of your pages code-behind so will have access to the private property set above. Put the code from your handler into this web method - bar the binding.

Comment: Ok, I am not familiar with Web Methods, but I think I found a code example that will help. Thanks

Comment: I'm having an issue accessing the DataTable from the WebMethod. How does it need to be declared?